# Methods for asp:FileUpload object?

Tags: asp.net, syntax, methods, file-upload

. .

I'm trying to set up an <asp:FileUpload> object to fire on the client side after I click "Browse" and select a file.  (Specifically, I want it to return the name of the file that was selected.)

However, I'm having a hard time trying to find the correct method.  None of the server-side methods do what I want (and I'd prefer it to fire on the client-side, anyway), and none of the various combinations of client-side methods (onclick, onchange, etc.) seem to work.

Ideas, anyone?

Thanks!

**Edit:** I think I may have answered my own question.  I ended up abandoning the ASP.NET <asp:FileUpload> tool, and simply used the lower-tech <input type="file"> instead.  Methods seem to work just fine with that.

**Edit #2:** Nothing doing.  That works fine on the client side, but then I have the problem of trying to save the file on the server side.  I guess it's back to Square 1.

**Edit #3:** I think this is the final answer.  I changed it back to <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploader"> and added a FileUploader.Attributes.Add to the Page_Load.  It sees that and fires with no problem.  Of course, now I'm getting an "Object expected" error (because the script it's calling comes after the code -- ah, the joys of dealing with JavaScript order).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my edit yesterday -- the answer ended up being to add the attributes in the Page_Load.  Let's say my FileUpload ID is "FileUploader".  I added **FileUploader.Attributes.Add("onchange","CallThisCode();")**.  That did the trick!

Now I just need to figure out how to make it call the JavaScript correctly -- a different issue altogether! :-)